# Socket.io disconnects and reconnects in Angular application

Tags: angular, socket.io

I have an Angular 8 application that communicates with a Node backend and uses [socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) 3.0.5 to receive real time events from the backend (which uses [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) 3.0.4). The operation is as follows:

1. When a user is logged in, a new socket connection is opened with `this.socket = io(API_URL)`
2. There are API calls that take a long time to finish (more than 25s), so they keep emitting information messages through the web sockets connection, so I can update the view in the frontend. We do this by passing a `channel_id` as a parameter, which is basically the event name we'll listen to to get the messages.
3. In the image below, I show the output of a batch process that executes 9 "compile" calls:

[image: Network calls]

The first 4 calls work perfectly, receiving all the socket messages. However, suddenly, I see some calls from the socket.io library (the ones starting by `?EIO=4&transport=polling`) that seems to cancel the existing websocket connection and start a new one, like you can see in the following image (sorry, the socket ids differ from the previous one as it's another run):

[image: New socket connection]

I don't do anything with the socket connection between the API calls. The code does the following:

1. (Before starting the calls) Create a `channel_id` and start listening on it using `this.socket.on(channelId, (event: any) => { ... });`
2. Use a `for` loop to do the API calls using the above `channel_id`, one by one
3. When all the calls are finished, use `socket.off` to "unsubscribe" from the socket messages

I've been doing a lot of tests but I can't find what's the reason of the disconnection and I don't know what else I could look. Anyone could give me some advice about what to check that could help me out with this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

After some tests, I found that the problem was not in the Angular app but in the backend. The compile process is very CPU intensive and it seems that, although all the internal logic is done with promises, the Node server gets overloaded and can't fulfill the rest of the tasks. So, when a socket "ping" message arrives, the server can't respond in the next 5 seconds and this is considered as a connection loss, so it tries to reconnect.

I've solved it incrementing the ping interval and timeout on the server startup:

```js
const _io: io.Server = new io.Server(this._server, {
  pingInterval: 100000,
  pingTimeout: 90000,
});
```

This is just a temporary patch, as the solution is to make use of some of the Node capabilities to handle CPU intensive tasks, as the worker threads, but this is another question ;)

Cheers,

Comment: Nice. Did you try store the connection object in a variable and reuse of the variable connection object is not null? That ways a retry interval is avoided. Your way may be prone to memory leaks

Comment: Hi! We create the socket io connection when the Node server starts, and keep it the same for all the connected users, do you mean this?

Comment: ok. What about creating new sockets when a client make a connection request? Is it done all the time a client tries to connect?

Comment: Yes, when a client logs in, we create a new socket using `this.socket = new io(API_URL)`. When the user logs out, we close the socket connection.

Comment: Ok cool. That should be fine I guess. I thought or read you create or check for a connection everytime a client sends a message and do a loop and unsubscribe. This method is susceptible for leaks if you miss